# Reading from Amazon S3 in Flink: UnsupportedFileSystemSchemeException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-flink

I am trying to read from an S3 bucket in a Java flink (version 1.11) application. I am trying to read from an S3 file into a DataSet object using the following code:

```
ExecutionEnvironment executionEnv = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
DataSet<String> dataSet = executionEnv.readTextFile("s3a://<bucket>/<key>");
```

Every time I try to run this I run into this error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.core.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemSchemeException: Could not find a file system implementation for scheme 's3a'
...
```

When I look at other posts about this error, it is because I need to configure flink-s3-fs-hadoop in my environment. I have tried configuring it for a while now, but the same error keeps occurring--I have the .jar for fink-s3-fs-hadoop in my plugins directory but it is not even recognized.

What are the steps for making this work within an IDE? All documentation online is very vague.

Comment: Hi Hoah,
Using a remote environment might be the way to go. Flink is primarily designed as a distributed system => when running it all in an IDE, corner cases like that are kinda expected. What's happening here is that a Flink makes the difference between the classpath of our code and the classpath of the plugin, otherwise tons of conflicts occur.

Comment: What I would suggest is to try to launch a Flink cluster on your computer, add the s3 in its plugin folder, then from your IDE start a `StreamExecutionEnvironment.createRemoteEnvironment(...)` pointing to that cluster. I've not tried this, though I'm hopeful it might help you achieve what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @Svend That makes a lot of sense, thanks for the recommendation. I am going to try setting up a local cluster. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Hi @Hoah, I assume you've ensured that `flink-s3-fs-hadoop` is on the classpath in your IDE project, and not just copied to your Flink installation's plugin directory, right?